# How to use myname2.lex in the flex examples?

Tags: flex-lexer

I see the following example in flex examples. I am able to compile it. But I am not sure what input I should give to it. Could anybody let me know? Thanks.

```
/*
 * myname2.lex : A sample Flex program
 *               that does token replacement.                      
 */

%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%x STRING
%%
\"                ECHO; BEGIN(STRING); 
<STRING>[^\"\n]*  ECHO;
<STRING>\"        ECHO; BEGIN(INITIAL);

%NAME     { printf("%s",getenv("LOGNAME")); }
%HOST     { printf("%s",getenv("HOST"));    }
%HOSTTYPE { printf("%s",getenv("HOSTTYPE"));}
%HOME     { printf("%s",getenv("HOME"));    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules `%NAME`, `%HOST`, `%HOSTTYPE` and `%HOME` match those exact strings respectively. So you could enter those and see their corresponding actions execute.

You could also enter one of them surrounded by quotes (e.g. `"%HOST"`) and observe that its action will not be executed because the whole thing was seen as a string literal.